# Cannot Implicitly Convert Type (FileHelpers) C#

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am trying to use FileHelpers and initialize the FileHelperEngine class.

```
 public partial class ReadFlashcards : Form
{
    public FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine<FlashcardPack>();

    public ReadFlashcards()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    public class FlashcardPack
    {
        public string pack;
        public string question;
        public string answer;
        public string image;
    }
}
```

Part of the line 3 --> `new FileHelperEngine<FlashcardPack>();` says `'Cannot implicitly convert type FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine<FlashcardsPack> to FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine'`
I have looked at the [documentation](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadFileDelimited/) and it looks the same as in my code (the public keyword doesn't make a difference and so does the var).

**How do I fix this?** Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not define it as `public FileHelperEngine<FlashcarPack> engine`?

Comment: Don't listen to documentation. Listen to the compiler. FileHelperEngine<T> doesn't extend FileHelperEngine. Change the type of your variable and move on.

Comment: @MikeH You cannot use `var` for a field, only for variables.

Comment: @juharr Thank you :)

Comment: @Juharr has the answer. You're declaring a field of type `FileHelperEngine` and then trying to assign it an instance of type `FileHelperEngine<T>`.

Comment: @juharr, you are, of course, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [source code](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/72f5515e2d04504a43b5b748c81789d8be91fe56/FileHelpers/Engines/FileHelperEngine.cs), you cannot convert `FileHelperEngine<FlashcardPack>` to `FileHelperEngine`.

```
public class FileHelperEngine : FileHelperEngine<object>
```

You need to use it in this way:

```
 public FileHelperEngine<FlashcardPack> engine = new FileHelperEngine<FlashcardPack>();
```